# Add media queries to Bootstrap 4 spacing generator

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Bootstrap 3 project and have lifted over some code from the new Bootstrap 4 in order to have classes like `my-1`, `pb-5` etc. It works fine for big screens. But when I look at the page using a small screen device the margins and padding are too huge. What would be a solution for this?

Here's the code which generates these classes ([_spacing.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/utilities/_spacing.scss)):

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
      @each $size, $length in $spacers {

        .#{$abbrev}#{$infix}-#{$size} { #{$prop}: $length !important; }
        .#{$abbrev}t#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-top: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}r#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-right: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}b#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}y#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-bottom: $length !important;
        }
        .#{$abbrev}l#{$infix}-#{$size},
        .#{$abbrev}x#{$infix}-#{$size} {
          #{$prop}-left: $length !important;
        }
      }
    }

    // Some special margin utils
    .m#{$infix}-auto { margin: auto !important; }
    .mt#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-top: auto !important;
    }
    .mr#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-right: auto !important;
    }
    .mb#{$infix}-auto,
    .my#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-bottom: auto !important;
    }
    .ml#{$infix}-auto,
    .mx#{$infix}-auto {
      margin-left: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the SASS code, the function accepts a breakpoint which is used to construct the `infix` that generates margin/padding classes that are responsive...

`m-sm-*`, `m-md-*`, `m-lg-*`, etc...

Of course Bootstrap 3 isn't going to utilize this in the same way since it doesn't have `$grid-breakpoints` array/map. You'll need to "lift over" some more code, or just switch entirely to Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Ohh nice, I did not notice the infix thing. Many thanks.